# CRM 2013 display 2 entities on a single form

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I'm developing CRM 2013 for the company that I'm working for, and they want whenever a user edits an account, the new edited account will be saved in a separate entity and will approve that account before update that old account.

So my question is there a way to display the old and new account on the same form? if not is there any suggestions on how it can be done? because they want to see what changes has been made before they approve the updates made to that account

Comment: Why do you not use the auditing functionality that comes with MS CRM instead of saving the changes to a new entity/record?
To display the changes you could embed a HTML webresource in your form (only shown on change).
Also: Are you aware that Autosave in MS CRM 2013 will make your task very difficult?

Comment: I have disabled auto save feature so it won't bother me, auditing won't help me much unless it doesn't have a restore feature which will restore it as it was if the manager has rejected the edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to support such a highly restrictive business process like your scenario you'll indeed have to store all the new values into a "Audit entity" and update the original record on approval.

To show you old and new values side by side you could create a custom form for your Account entity which consist of a html webresource containing the modified attributes.

The html webresource will contain the JavaScript logic to retrieve both the latest "Audit entity" and the corresponding Account attributes.

In your standard Account form, override the Save event and write any changed attribute to a new "Audit entity" record.

Make this custom form only available to your audit supervisors by assigning it to a dedicated security role.

Comment: I agree with this solution except I would manage displaying, accepting and rejecting changes on the Account Audit entity side and leave the Account side clean.  Like Filburt suggests on save of an account you would set account status to pending review and create an Account Audit which you could then assign to an administrator for action.  The Account Audit would display the changes and give the administrator an option to accept or reject them.  If the changes are rejected then the values would be written back to the account.  I would add logic to lock the account while it is pending review.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any out of the box functionality that supports this. Like @Filburt said, auditing is supposed to be the proper way to handle this.

Have you considered creating a workflow that on the update of the account will change the status reason of the account to "Pending Approval" and then notify whom ever is in charge of approvals to approve the change?

This way someone who looks at the case knows that something hasn't been approved yet (And can check the audit history to see what that change was), and you could even include some javascript on the account form to throw an alert.

Comment: if I use the audit which looks like a good way to use it, is there a way to restore back to how it was if the approval was rejected?

Comment: Not programmatically, but it does store what the value was before it was changed, so it's quite easy to change back manually. 

How often are you expecting to deny changes?

Comment: well not much once the edit is approved it can't be rejected so it shouldn't be much frequent I will check more about auditing

Comment: If that doesn't do what you need, you can always use an external program to do it. Avepoint Record rollback does exactly what you are suggesting. I don't know if there is a way to automate it, but if you have some money in your budget it might be worth looking at.